# Error with multiple spring boot security config

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot application already secured with JWT and I want to secure the spring actuator endpoint with basic auth in-memory user so I modified the Security config class to include 2 methods

Spring version 2.6.4

## The problem

when I set the "ActuatorSecurityConfigurerAdapter" order to -1 and test with user1:user1 I get this error and my API becomes unsecured

```
JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint: Responding with unauthorized error. Message - Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

when I set the "ActuatorSecurityConfigurerAdapter" order to 2 i can access both endpoints with JWT

**Security Config Class**

---

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    
    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public class ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private final CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService;
        private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
        private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

        public ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter(CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService, JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler, JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
            this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
            this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
            this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
        }

        @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(Endpoints.AUTH_ENDPOINT+"/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();

            http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }


    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public class ActuatorSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasRole("MODERATOR")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user1")
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1"))
                    .authorities("MODERATOR");
        }


    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: please read the spring security official documentation as to properly implement the handling of JWTs using the spring security built in JWTFilter. Custom security is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

## Problem Solved

1. I put Order(1) for the actuator security and Order(2) for the rest of my API
2. To use the in-memory user I had to add "ROLE_" prefix for the authorities like **ROLE_MODERATOR**  and in the HTTP security method I just added .hasRole("MODERATOR")

and this is the final SecurityConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Configuration
    public class ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        private final CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService;
        private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
        private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

        public ApiSecurityConfigurationAdapter(CustomUserDetailsServiceImpl customUserDetailsService, JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler, JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter) {
            this.customUserDetailsService = customUserDetailsService;
            this.unauthorizedHandler = unauthorizedHandler;
            this.jwtAuthenticationFilter = jwtAuthenticationFilter;
        }

        @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors().and().csrf().disable()
                    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers(Endpoints.AUTH_ENDPOINT + "/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                    .authenticated();

            http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    public class ActuatorSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint actuatorAuthenticationEntryPoint;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                    .cors().and()
                    .csrf().disable().
                    exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(actuatorAuthenticationEntryPoint).and()
                    .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                    .antMatcher(Endpoints.ACTUATOR_ENDPOINT+"/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user1")
                    .password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1"))
                    .authorities("ROLE_ADMIN");
        }
    }
}
```